# Form alter on date parts

Tags: forms

I'm trying to add attributes to a date form field. The field renders as day month year in separate inputs.

I cannot work out how to add the form alter to these specific inputs.

I've tried variations of the form array as you can see below.

```
function xxx_form_user_register_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

  $form["field_date_of_birth_boxed"][LANGUAGE_NONE]["value"]["day"]["#attributes"]["pattern"] = "\d*";
  $form["field_date_of_birth_boxed"][LANGUAGE_NONE]["value"]["day"]["#attributes"]["maxlength"] = "155";
  $form["field_date_of_birth_boxed"][LANGUAGE_NONE]["value"]["day"]["#attributes"]["placeholder"] = "156";

}
```

I've ran it through debug on PHPStorm and can see the attributes there but at render they're not displaying.

I've also tried variations on the above array structure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Drupal 7 right?

Comment: In which method are you altering the form?

Comment: Drupal 7 NoSweat.

Comment: @plocks I've just noticed it's not in the hook_form_alter method it looks like a custom function. This could well be where I am going wrong.

form_mod_standard_elements(&$form, &$form_state) { ...

Comment: I'll suggest you put it into hook_form_alter and report back.

Comment: Still no joy.  I put it in a hook_form_alter function but still the values, aren't changing.

Comment: Show the entire function

Comment: @BearWithNoHair it'd be best if you could update the question with the new code parts.

Comment: I'm using hook_form_form_id_alter and I've updated the question as per @plocks suggestion.